# radio buttom value to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get the value of radio button to change the value of hidden input
so if i have those 2 radio buttons with value 1 and 2
i want to accomplished on js so it will be live change

> if radio value = 1 
>   the value of the hidden  button change to ex "Paris" 
>   if radio value = 2 
>   the value of the hidden  button change to ex "Cairo"

here is the radio buttons

```
<input id="shop" name="shop" type="radio" class="field radio" value="1" tabindex="10"    />
<input id="shop" name="shop" type="radio" class="field radio" value="2" tabindex="11"    />
```

and here is the hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" size="30" id="fromInput" name="from" value="" />
```

Thank You

Comment: first of all `id` should be unique

Comment: if( $('input[name="shop"]').val() == 1 ) { $('#fromInput').val(1); } else {  $('#fromInput').val(2); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$('input[name="shop"]:radio').change(function(){
   var val = (this.value == 1)? 'Paris' : 'Cairo'; //set var val to Paris if value of selected radio button is 1 else set val to Cairo
   $('#fromInput').val(val); //set var val to value of element with id fromInput
});
```

---

ID must be unique use class instead

your both radio button's have same id change it class.

```
<input class="shop" name="shop" type="radio" class="field radio" value="1" tabindex="10"    />
<input class="shop" name="shop" type="radio" class="field radio" value="2" tabindex="11"    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery **[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** to handle the change event

```
$('input[name="shop"][type="radio"]').change(function(){
     $('#fromInput').val(this.value == 1 ? 'paris' : 'cairo');
})
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/7Be3x/2/)</kbd>

> Note:  ID should be unique in a page , It's better to use class instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="shop"]:radio').on( 'change', function(){
  if( $(this).val() == 1 ) { 
    $('#fromInput').val(1); 
  } else { 
    $('#fromInput').val(2); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`ID` Should not be given more then Once,Id is Unique for each element,use class if you want to get element at once,And apply `.change()` of Jquery.

**HTML :**

```
  <input class="shop" name="shop" type="radio" class="field radio" value="1" tabindex="10"/>
  <input class="shop" name="shop" type="radio" class="field radio" value="2" tabindex="11"    />
  <input type="hidden" size="30" id="fromInput" name="from" value="" />
```

**JS:**

```
 $('.shop').change(function(){

  var place = ( $(this).val()==1?"Paris":"Cairo" );
  $('#fromInput').val(place);
  alert($('#fromInput').val());
})
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/37ajG/)

May this will help you...